# SSRS - Error message in SELECT Statement

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

Is there a way to re-write this SELECT query to avoid error?
Whenever I run the query below, I get this error message:
"An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ';'. Incorrect syntax near 'LoanAmountGroup'. Incorrect syntax near 'LoanAmountGroupOrder'."

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   CASE WHEN LoanAmnt & lt; = 100000 THEN 'Less Than $100k' 
        WHEN LoanAmnt BETWEEN 100000 AND 200000 THEN '$100k to $200k' 
        WHEN LoanAmnt & gt;200000 THEN 'More Than $200k' 
    END LoanAmntGroup, 
    CASE WHEN LoanAmnt & lt; = 100000 THEN 1 
        WHEN LoanAmnt BETWEEN 100000 AND 200000 THEN 2 
        WHEN LoanAmnt & gt; 200000 THEN 3 
    END LoanAmntGroupOrder

FROM    dbo.Fact_Finance
ORDER BY LoanAmntGroupOrder
```

I am using SQL Manager

Comment: You need to remove the ` & lt;` with `<` and `& gt;` for `>` in your query.

Comment: Thank you Coder of Code. I removed '& lt' along with '& gt' and replaced them with the less than and greater than signs. And it worked.                SELECT DISTINCT 
   CASE WHEN LoanAmnt < = 100000 THEN 'Less Than $100k' 
  WHEN LoanAmnt BETWEEN 100000 AND 200000 THEN '$100k to $200k' 
  WHEN LoanAmnt > 200000 THEN 'More Than $200k' 
 END LoanAmntGroup, 
 CASE WHEN LoanAmnt < = 100000 THEN 1 
  WHEN LoanAmnt BETWEEN 100000 AND 200000 THEN 2 
  WHEN LoanAmnt > 200000 THEN 3 
 END LoanAmntGroupOrder

FROM    dbo.Fact_Finance
ORDER BY LoanAmntGroupOrder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ou need to remove the `& lt;` with `<` and `& gt;` for `>` in your query.You can try your query like this,

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
         CASE WHEN LoanAmnt <= 100000 THEN 'Less Than $100k' 
              WHEN LoanAmnt BETWEEN 100000 AND 200000 THEN '$100k to $200k' 
              WHEN LoanAmnt > 200000 THEN 'More Than $200k' 
         END LoanAmntGroup, 
        CASE WHEN LoanAmnt <= 100000 THEN 1 
             WHEN LoanAmnt BETWEEN 100000 AND 200000 THEN 2 
             WHEN LoanAmnt > 200000 THEN 3 
        END LoanAmntGroupOrder
    FROM    dbo.Fact_Finance
    ORDER BY LoanAmntGroupOrder
```